# JavaScript not working on all tabs on single HTML page

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-ui-tabs

So I am working on a website that is suppose to have little interactive pictures maps that you can hover over and it will display information. But the problem that I am having is that my Javascript is not working on all of the tabs on the page, it is only working on the first tab and I cannot figure out why. I first I thought it was because I called on the map and overlay ID twice, but I changed that by adding map1 and overlay1 so that there was no overlap.

```js
     $('area').each(function(){
        var area = $(this),
            alt = area.attr('alt');
  area.mouseenter(function(){
            $('#overlay').html(alt);
        }).mouseleave(function(){
      $('#overlay').html('');

  });
 });
    
    function openEmail(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
     evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

    }
```

```css
    
    #map {
        position: relative;
    }
    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
    }

    #map1 {
        position: relative;
    }

    #overlay1 {
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
    }  

    .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    /* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
    }
```

```html
<figure class = "tab">
    <button class = "tablinks" onclick = "openEmail(event, 'phishing')">Classic Phishing</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick = "openEmail(event, 'ceo-scam')">CEO Scam</button>
</figure>

<figure id = "phishing" class = "tabcontent">

  <!-- where the phishing map is -->
  <figure id = "map">
      <figure id = "overlay"></figure>
    <img src = "" width = "805" height = "531" alt = "classic-phishing" usemap = "#phishingmap" /> 
  </figure>
  <!-- map with the coordinates and the alt that text is displayed -->
  <map name = "phishingmap">
    <area href = "" alt="You need to check where the email originated from since anybody can spoof an email address." title="" shape="rect" coords="74,29,261,51"/>
    </map>
</figure> 
<figure id = "ceo-scam" class = "tabcontent">
    <!-- where the phishing map is -->
  <figure id = "map1">
    <figure id = "overlay1"></figure>
    <img src = "" width = "860" height = "400" alt = "ceo-scam" usemap = "#ceomap" /> 
  </figure>
  <!-- map with the coordinates and the alt that text is displayed -->
  <map name = "ceomap">
    <area href = "" alt="This looks like an email within the company, however you need to be careful with anything you receive. Always check email headers to see where an email actually originated from." title="from-boss" coords="85,32,261,58" shape="rect"/>
    </map>
</figure>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code dealing with the mouseover is targeting an element with id `overlay`.  The second tab has an ID of `overlay1`.  A solution would be to add a class to both figures and target that class in the first portion of your JS dealing with mouseenter events.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like when I added the new overlay and map tags, i forgot to update the javascript along with it.